# Google sheets redirecting link is not downloadable

Tags: curl, redirect, google-sheets, download, wget

[SOLVED] I'm trying to download a Google Sheet in TSV format from terminal using `wget`, `curl -L` or `gdown`. The first link I try to download in this format

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SPREADHEET_ID>/export?format=tsv&gid=<GID>`

It downloads an `html` file which says that the file temporarily moved to some other link. And when I follow the redirected link (`-L` option for `curl`) all I get is another `html` file that belongs to the opening page of google sheets.

So this link:
[google sheets about page](https://www.google.ca/sheets/about/)

I need to do this download from the terminal, I can't do it using google's web page, how else can I download a Google Spreadsheet from the terminal?

EDIT: Even though I got a shareable link, I didn't provide a user who is able to view that link. The problem was solved when I did. If the spreadsheet is not open to public, apparently getting a shareable link is not enough.

Comment: If you don't want to use the access token and API key, is the Spreadsheet shared publicly? And can you provide the wget or curl command including the endpoint for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information about the Spreadsheet ID.

Comment: Can you please provide your solution process detailed so more people can benefit from your question and answer? Thank you.